# I want to add a label border in the layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, label

I want to make a label look exactly like

[image]

iphone button.

In my case I want to show Active but I want the border of label like given image.
need XML code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create button_background.xml in drawable folder and paste this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item > 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <padding android:left="10dip" android:right="10dip" android:top="5dip" android:bottom="5dip"/>
        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" 
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp"/> 

        <solid 
            android:color="#f5f5f5"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#42A5F5"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```